# Monad Maybeのreturnの実装はどこ？

Tags: haskell

モナド則のひとつ `右恒等性`を確かめていました。

```
Just 5 >>= return -- 結果: Just 5
```

こんな `return関数`はどのように実装するんだろうと思って

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html の

下記画像下部の`return :: a -> Maybe a      # Source` の Sourceと書かれた部分にあたるリンクに飛んでみると下記でした。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#return

おそらくこのリンクが飛んだのは下記引用箇所の `return      = pure` の部分だと思うのですが、これが return の実装なのでしょうか？

> ```
> class Applicative m => Monad m where
>     -- | Sequentially compose two actions, passing any value produced
>     -- by the first as an argument to the second.
>     --
>     -- \'@as '>>=' bs@\' can be understood as the @do@ expression
>     --
>     -- @
>     -- do a <- as
>     --    bs a
>     -- @
>     (>>=)       :: forall a b. m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
>
>     -- | Sequentially compose two actions, discarding any value produced
>     -- by the first, like sequencing operators (such as the semicolon)
>     -- in imperative languages.
>     --
>     -- \'@as '>>' bs@\' can be understood as the @do@ expression
>     --
>     -- @
>     -- do as
>     --    bs
>     -- @
>     (>>)        :: forall a b. m a -> m b -> m b
>     m >> k = m >>= \_ -> k -- See Note [Recursive bindings for Applicative/Monad]
>     {-# INLINE (>>) #-}
>
>     -- | Inject a value into the monadic type.
>     return      :: a -> m a
>     return      = pure
> ```

同じ理屈で、 `>>=` もソースのリンク先が

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%3E%3E%3D

なのですが、他の[解説サイト](https://qiita.com/suin/items/0255f0637921dcdfe83b)でみてるのとぜんぜん形がちがうように思います。

上記解説サイトから 実装部分を引用します。

> ```
> instance Monad Maybe where
>     Nothing >>= func = Nothing
>     Just val >>= func  = func val
> ```

なので、てっきり

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    Nothing >>= func = Nothing
    Just val >>= func  = func val
    return .....
```

みたいな形で書かれているページに遷移されると思っていたのですが....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> おそらくこのリンクが飛んだのは下記引用箇所の `return      = pure` の部分だと思うのですが、これが return の実装なのでしょうか？

はい。それが`Maybe`における`return`の実装です。
型クラスはメソッドを定義する際、メソッドのデフォルトの実装も同時に定義することができます。そうすることによって、このように`Maybe`をはじめとする型が`Monad`を実装する際、`return`の実装を書かなくても済むわけですね。

結果、`instance Monad Maybe where` のブロックには`return`の実装がないため、飛び先が`class Applicative m => Monad m where`にあるデフォルトの実装になったわけです。

なお、なんで`return      = pure`がデフォルトの実装になっているかは[Haskell: Monadクラスのこれまでとこれから - Qiita](https://qiita.com/mod_poppo/items/8c483951703b5ea0f74e)が参考になるかと思います。

> 同じ理屈で、 >>= もソースのリンク先が

`>>=` については`return`のリンク先が`Monad`のデフォルト実装になっていた関係で、勘違いしてしまったのでしょう。
実際には https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#%3E%3E%3D に書かれているのは `Maybe` の`Monad`インスタンスの定義ではなく、`Monad`型クラス自体の定義です。
`Maybe`の`Monad`インスタンスにおける`>>=`の定義は、ちゃんと
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.14.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#line-1005
にあります。言及されている記事のものとよく似ていますね。

余談:

確かに私もこの飛び先については時々混乱します...
わからなくなったらURLを見たりスクロールしたりして、自分がどこにいるか確認してみてください。

Comment: つまり本体（実装）は親（？）の `instance Applicative Maybe where
    pure = Just` ですね？

Comment: そうです！ご名答！